# add days to given timestamp (YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.sss) in lua script

Tags: lua

#### Summary

I would like to add 1 day to given timestamp in lua script.

#### My try

```
local creation_date = "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000" 

local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli = creation_date:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+).(%d+)'

local dt = y .. '-' .. m .. '-'..d.. ' '..Hr..':'..Min..'-'..Sec..'.'..Milli
print(dt)

local new_ts = os.time
    { year = y, month = m, day = d,
      hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec, mill=Milli } + 1*24*60*60
  
print(new_ts)
```

I am getting new_ts = `1452470400`

#### Expected result

2016-01-01 00:01:00.000 (in this format only)

Comment: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.time -- What you're getting is what the manual says you should expect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest you may be able to get is something like this:

```lua
local creation_date = "2016-01-01 00:00:00.000"

local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli = creation_date:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+).(%d+)'

local dt = y .. '-' .. m .. '-'..d.. ' '..Hr..':'..Min..'-'..Sec..'.'..Milli
print(dt)

local new_ts = os.time { year = y, month = m, day = d, hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec } + 1*24*60*60

print(string.format("%s.%03d", os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", new_ts), Milli))
```

The `Mill` entry in the table that you pass on to `os.time()` is being ignored, and the resulting value doesn't provide millisecond precision, so there's no point in including it. To get the format you desire, you need `os.date()` with an appropriate format, and then you can append the milliseconds to that again, manually.

With that, it looks like this:

```
$ lua script.lua
2016-01-01 00:00-00.000
2016-01-02 00:00:00.000
```

With the suggestion from @Nifim it can be simplified further, confirmed by the documentation

> When the function is called, the values in these fields do not need to be inside their valid ranges. For instance, if sec is -10, it means 10 seconds before the time specified by the other fields; if hour is 1000, it means 1000 hours after the time specified by the other fields. - [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual: os.time](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.time)

```lua
local creation_date = "2016-01-31 00:00:00.000"

local y, m, d, Hr, Min, Sec, Milli = creation_date:match '(%d+)-(%d+)-(%d+) (%d+):(%d+):(%d+).(%d+)'

local dt = y .. '-' .. m .. '-'..d.. ' '..Hr..':'..Min..'-'..Sec..'.'..Milli
print(dt)

local new_ts = os.time { year = y, month = m, day = d + 1, hour = Hr, min = Min, sec = Sec }

print(string.format("%s.%03d", os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", new_ts), Milli))
```

Output:

```
$ lua script.lua
2016-01-31 00:00-00.000
2016-02-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: you can just add 1 to the `day` value so `day = d + 1`, this works even when the day is the last of the month or last of the year. Just mentioning it as it is a bit cleaner than `+ 1*24*60*60`

Comment: Any option to convert the result timestamp to timestamp data type, because `print(string.format("%s.%03d", os.date("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", new_ts), Milli))` is giving string value. I need it completely in timestamp format not in string type.

Comment: What is a “timestamp format”, can you give an example? Do you need (partial )seconds since epoch (1970-1-1) for instance, or something else?